# How can I detect an .exe file that is produced by vb6 and recognize different vb6 files from each other?

Tags: vb6, detection, file-format

I'm writing a program to detect which ".exe" file is generated by "Visual Basic6". I found that at the "entry point" of each vb file, there is an address at offset 1 from "entry point" which points to a location that contains the string: "vb5!", is that a certain signature? Can I be sure that in every vb files this string is exist?
Then, I want to find the certain address of the beginning of the code, so that I can recognize every vb file from an other vb file.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to detect malwares that are created with vb, I'm trying to write an application that can automatically recognize them.

Comment: Errmm, not every program written in VB6 is malware! There are many many useful programs written in VB6. Surely you should just get a good anti-virus / anti-spyware package? There are [plenty of free packages](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=1&oq=free+an&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGLL_en-GBGB320GB324&q=free+antivirus)

Comment: @MarkJ: I don't know what he's trying to do, but I doubt he's trying to write his own anti-virus program.

Comment: Hi MArkJ, I know that every program written in VB are not malware, I've collected some malware, one of the biggest group is written in vb, so I'm trying to detect them automatically.

Comment: egrunin is true! I'm trying to start that :)

Comment: @egrunin I sincerely doubt it's a good idea to write your own anti-virus program, but I'm afraid that's exactly what `rain` is trying to do. See his comment just above. @rain writing anti-virus software is hard and you're going about it the wrong way. No offence, but I don't think you're going to achieve anything useful by this effort.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but every VB6 exe, DLL or OCX will contain an import to MSVBVM60.dll. If it contains that, you can be pretty sure it's a VB6 exe.

About this

> Then, I want to find the certain
>   address of the beginning of the code,
>   so that I can recognize every vb file
>   from an other vb file.

VB6 doesn't embed the same kind of metadata in the exe that .net does, so it'll be impossible to extract any "VB Code" from the executable. Depending on how it was compiled, you MIGHT be able to retrieve functionnames and such, but that's only if the PDB (program database) was embedded into the exe and not compiled into a seperate PDB file.

Worse, there are plenty of tools out there to compress an exe (any exe), and if that's done, there's almost no way you'll be able to tell where the exe came from, at least not from simply looking at the contents of the exe file.

Comment: You're right, the PDB is not available in almost 100% of files! In programs which are written in VSC++ (for example) there is call to the start of the main code that is not a part of the compiler, but in VB I still found nothing :(, I don't want to pars all the file, the time is so important for me. And I know this way I only could detect files that are not packed, compressed or crypted ... , but it is worthy for me.